# ADTF .dat trace file reader

Tags: adtf

I am working on ADTF .dat trace file. I need to read these files without using ADTF tools. The trace file is of FLEXRAY. I would like to know is there any open source tool/library to read such file Or, can anyone guide me how do i proceed to read this file? I would really appreciate anyone help on this.

Answer (score 2):

For read and write access to (adtf)dat files there is the ADTF File Library a.k.a. IFHD the best option, which is the base for ADTF 3.x and can also handle the file structure from ADTF 2.x.

Please have a look at https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-file-library/v0/html/index.html

There is an example how to access the information https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-file-library/v0/html/a02069.html

The Lib itself comes completely open source licensed and can be consumed by digitalwerk artifactory / conan: https://artifactory.digitalwerk.net/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/dw-developer-sdk/dw/ifhd/0.5.0/stable

Depends on your use case but if you want to inspect or export data using UI, the DAT GUI Tools are also open source and implementing the IFHD: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-dat-gui-tools/v0/guides/index.html

And download here as well: https://artifactory.digitalwerk.net/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/dw-public-releases/aev25/ADTF_DatTools/0.1.0/stable

But note: To interpret the flexray stream, you have to extend the functionality with the devtb2 deserializer plugin provided by device toolbox 3.1.0, in case the data has been recorded using ADTF 2.x. because ADTF 2.x itself does not know about Flexray... In case your dat file is from ADTF 3.x, everything will work. The file access example has the option to.load the additional adtffileplugin for that. This means you can read without ADTF but you need the component from the Device Toolbox.

The artifactory frontent is ugly. Here is a short way to use it for IFHD:

To find a package, see [image]

And to download, see [image]

Here is the link to IFHD for Windows / VS2017 / VS141 / Build Type: Release package from the screenshots -> https://artifactory.digitalwerk.net/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/dw-developer-sdk/dw/ifhd/0.5.0/stable/package/66cf6fe195939f36e2bceb8ce0ae147f3a8285e6/conan_package.tgz

Comment: I don't see any way to download the IFHD library at links you provide. Since the library is said to be open source, where can I find its source?

Comment: You should use conan because its made for it. The artifactory frontend is... well. Anyway, in the artifactory link you have to choose a package on left tree. There are 4 packages, for each platform and build type. Choose for example windows and release, expand it and right click on the archive package and download. The source code of the examples is inside the package. The source code of the library itself is currently hosted indide digitalwerk platform  depends on your company to have access. Stay tuned to publish to github. But.with the package and examples you will be full productive.

Comment: I see no such things there. Maybe it is showing different things when you are logged in? [BTW: There is no way to create an account there] Conan is not working either - complains about "Missing prebuilt package for 'a_util/5.5.0@dw/stable'".

Comment: Seems to be an off topic conan bug... Guess you are not using version 1.12.3 which is required, maybe yours is too new... or your platform/VC toolchain is different... anyway, this is off topic, lets try to "fix" the ugly frontend bug. You do not need to login, just search for your package, I will update the answer to give some screenshots

Comment: Thanks for your input. The data is being recorded on ADTF 2.13. I am very new to this ADTF and I am not sure if its very basic questions.  For the 2.x, how do i proceed? 
I need to create a reader that can read ADTF 2.x  .dat trace file.

Comment: Well, basically you do not have to care about the recorded version the reader will manage it for you. The only "problem" is the mentioned flexray stream. So you need the adtffileplugin from device toolbox 3.1.0. you can also define the reader to skip unknown streams, have a look at the sdk documentation for that. But I guess using the the file access example in combination with the deserialzer adtffileplugin to aupport.flexray stream is the best start for you to get a feeling about reading from dat files

Comment: Hi @C-3PFLO, Thanks alot for the information. I am still not able to compile them. I downloaded the same version of ifhd, a_util and ddl. The Readme says to build a_utils and ddl. but i donot see the cmake for them. I guess they are already built. I really appreciate your help to advise on this.

Comment: ddl and a_utils are only required if you want to compile the ifhd library. The cmake is in the source package which Ou neither have nor need. All you need are the binaries of ifhd. The link brings you an already build binary package, also with compiled examples. To adapt or recompile the examples, all you need is already inside the ifhd binary package. There is also the cmake for the examples

Comment: @C-3PFLO- I wanted to recompile the examples program but it doesnot work. I am trying to run the fileaccess.cpp. I ran the cmake through my command line which doesnot compile and throws erros saying the adtf: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package): Could not find a configuration file for package "adtf_file" that is compatible with requested version "". I am little confused on CMakeLists.txt file on : set(EXAMPLE fileaccess) #to not exceed 260 chars on path under windows... Which path should be set, I tried replacing the fileaccess with its path on cmake file and windows path.

Comment: OK, then you need a_util and ddl from the artifactory as well. use the source folder on the <root> dir of ifhd, then you can create a example solution, e.g. in <root>/build. just adapt utils and ddl cmake path, I would also suggest to define the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX as well on <roto> so the examples will be placed in <root>/bin automatically. Be aware to don't mix up build types, that won't work here... so if you are downloading release or debug, make sure the build type is the same in a_util, ddl and your example solution

Comment: @C-3PFLO
Thanks, I tried all way and was not able to fit a proper way. So I thought of using the  already created exe file. I tried using the fileaccess but it needs a csv , i am not sure which csv file it needs. I am sure its not a new csv file name as i tried it and throws a error :
no type deserializer for 'adtf.type.can.adtf2_support.serialization.adtf.cid' available
After that, I thought to give a try to GUI, and I am not able to do exactly same as GUINFO tool. Would it be possible, if you can have look in either of them. I just want to read the file and extract the signal values

Comment: @Surendra the csv file be created and does not have a connection to the error. As mentioned, you need the adtffileplugin from Device Toolbox to interpret can data from ADTF 2.x. Thats what the error says. As you can see in the code, you can extend the exe call with additional adtffileplugins. Anyway, I think we cannot solve the problem here. The inital question was about the library so this should be solved now ?

Comment: @Surendra Furthermore you cannot extract signals using this example or an own implementation without a database parser. By the way, since yesterday the file lib is on github -> https://github.com/AEV but you still have to challenge some basic cmake to compile and still can use the precompiled packages from before. I guess you should contact your ADTF support how to solve this issue, showing some data and what exactly you want to achieve, where you need the extracted signals and stuff. Out of the box, without device toolbox and plugins -> wont work

Answer (score 1):

Update 2020: adtf_file (ifhd) is now available on github

- https://github.com/AEV/adtf_file
- https://github.com/AEV/ddl
- https://github.com/AEV/a_util